# Dynamically read JSON data using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a URL which outputs JSON data when called. I have to check for a specific word in that JSON output. Example below -

```
r1 = session.get(authurl, headers=headers, timeout=6)
resphead = r1.headers.get('content-type')
if 'application/json' in resphead:
    json_data = r1.json()
    overallstatus1 = str((json_data['status']))
    overallstatus2 = str((json_data['status']['code']))
```

Sometimes, the output will have to be called using `['status']['code']` and sometimes the *code* section will not be coming up in the output, i.e. just `['status']`. Similarly, i'll have many other status to check which differ in the same way.

What can be done here to read the output even if the keys change.

Kindly clarify.

Comment: I suggest you, before accessing to check if the node you need exists: `if "value" in json_data: output=json_data['value']` and do this for all nested nodes

Answer (score 0):

When you call `.json()` on your response object it returns a python `dict`. Therefore you can take advantage of the build-in function `get()` of the dictionaries that returns a key if it exists in the dictionary, otherwise some pre-specified value (defalt is `None`)

From the docs: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

The calls at your code would then be

```
overallstatus1 = str(json_data.get('status'))
overallstatus2 = str(json_data.get('status', {}).get('code'))
```

Comment: I edited your code because if `'status'` isn't present then `json_data.get('status').get('code')` will fail, but on second thought the question seems to imply that it's always present, so `json_data['status']` should be fine.

Comment: Sure, thanks for your suggestions. i'll try them out.